# Webpack hangs during SSR build- Angular 12

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm running webpack v5.50 for server side rendering build for Angular project with following configuration

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts',
  },
  
  externals: {
   './dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
  },
  
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },

  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'app',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /polyfills-.*\.js/,
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} 
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

but post Angular 12 upgrade the same build hangs after emit without resolution for several hours and errors out finally as below

```
 [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting emit
 [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting emit
 [webpack.Progress] 98% emitting after emit
 [webpack.Progress] 98% emitting after emit
 [webpack.Progress] 99% done plugins
 [webpack.Progress] 99% done plugin
 [webpack.Progress] 99% cache store build dependencies
 [webpack.Progress] 99% cache store build dependencies
 [webpack.Progress] 99% cache begin idle
 [webpack.Progress] 99% cache begin idle
 [webpack.Progress] 100% 
 [webpack.Progress] 100% 
 /node_modules/webpack/lib/stats/DefaultStatsPrinterPlugin.js:1183
                return match.replace(content, format(content));
                             ^
 
 RangeError: Invalid string length
     at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    /node_modules/webpack/lib/stats/DefaultStatsPrinterPlugin.js:1183:18
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
```

P.S : Node - 16.19.1, Webpack - 5.50, Typescript - 4.3.5,"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18" which internally installs webpack 5.50 version for compiling SSR build

Comment: can you share a reproduce of the problem in github?

Comment: @Robert , src code cant be uploaded elsewhere due to compliance issues , found a similar issue  with no resolution as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240046/webpack-error-in-webpack-lib-stats-defaultstatsprinterplugin-js1248 -

Comment: to be compliance, you can't share only the link, but if you have a description and a link it's okay

Comment: @Robert , could you pls elaborate on what all files you will be requiring :)

Comment: I want to understand your setup, because the official way of angular ssr doesn't have any webpack configuration, so the whole thing is ambiguous for me, that's why I want a reproduce of your setup, just make replicate your setup with AppComonent being only hello world

Comment: @Robert , PFA the guide with minimal reproduction i've used to set up the project https://medium.com/upstate-interactive/how-to-build-an-angular-app-with-server-side-rendering-f7f415b851c8

Comment: it's very old one, you should stop doing that, please just use `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` as documented here https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: you can see the article is 5 years old, please in the future be careful when reading old content